# Kuntres by Rav Asher Weiss

Tags: history, oral-torah

In this [shiur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmBzysa7PKU), Rav Asher Weiss references a kuntres he wrote called על הראשונים ועל האחרונים on the development of Torah Shebeal Peh. Does anyone know if it is available online?

Comment: Could be something in [this](https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/RavDaf/RavInfoD.aspx?RavID=7) list

Comment: Didn't look like it to me.

Comment: If you want to know if it's available for purchase, I emailed his shamash (tvuna1@gmail.com) once asking where to get his hagadah. They responded with the info I needed to know.

Comment: @robev Does his shamash read English?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have asked the office of R Asher Weiss and they responded

> The kuntres על הראשונים ועל האחרונים is part of a kuntres וזאת תורת
> המנחה that was  given out by Mechon Minchas Asher about the Rav’s
> Derech Halimud. It is not available on line but it can be bought in
> Yerushalaim in the Rav’s Shul.

Comment: @N.T. If this is very important to you, I have a friend who works with the Rav. I could ask him if he can get a copy mailed to you. If important let me know and I will try and make it happen

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort you put in to answering this question. It went far beyond my expectations.  I assume shipping would be too expensive.  IY"H I could purchase it if I get to go there.